# Cannot click and select item in a listview (WPF)

Tags: wpf

I have a listview with following column

```
 <GridViewColumn Header="name" local:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Name">
   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Style="{StaticResource txtEditable}" KeyDown="SeqRenameTextBox_KeyDown" LostFocus="SeqRenameTextBox_LostFocus" />
     </DataTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
<GridViewColumn>
 ...
</GridViewColumn>
```

The problem is when I click on the TextBox, the listview doesn't select the item. Only when I click on the other normal column it will select the item.

Is there anything (e.g. TextBox inside) that will block the ListView from select the item?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the style txtEditable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the default behavior!

The text box will grab focus and it will not get to the listview item! What you can do as a hack is in your item container subscribe to the preview mouse down event and force a selectection of the listviewitem!